# Functional Testing Node/Express App with Google's reCAPTCHA

Tags: node.js, selenium, express, recaptcha, functional-testing

Is there a way to selectively disable middleware during testing? Or am I missing a fundamental concept that would help me out with my problem?

Background: I'm writing some functional tests to document a partially written website that uses Nodejs and Express. So far I'm writing my tests using selenium-webdriver, Mocha and Chai for my tests. I'm not against changing application code or testing tools. My questions is how do I work with my Google reCAPTCHA while testing? Currently it's loaded into my registration form and validated using middleware. I could disable the reCAPTCHA if the process.env.NODE_ENV is set to test but I feel like completely disabling it would not be testing the whole site. Here's some relevant code.

Controller:

```
  r.route('/register')
  .get(
    userController.getReturnURL,
    userController.registerForm
  )
  .post(
    userController.validateRegistrationForm,
    userController.validateGoogleCaptcha,
    catchErrors(userController.insertUser),
    catchErrors(userController.sendEmailValidation),
    authController.login
  );
```

The userController.validateGoogleCaptcha method

```
exports.validateGoogleCaptcha = (req, res, next) => {

  const data = {
    secret: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
    response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response'],
  };
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}&response=${req.body['g-recaptcha-response']}`,
    data: data,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
  })
    .then(function (response) {

      req.body.captchaSuccess = response.data.success;
      next();

    })
    .catch(function (response) {

      req.flash('error','Sorry! There was an error on our side in confirming your humanity with Google\'s reCAPTCHA service. Please try again, if you continue to have problems please <a href="/contact">contact us</a>.');

      // register form takes advantage of Google's reCAPTCHA and we need to load the script in the <head> element.
      req.body.jsScripts = ['https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'];
      return res.render('user/registrationForm', {title: 'Register your Personal Account', body: req.body, flashes: req.flash()});

    });
};
```

My Functional Registration Tests So Far

```
const ...


describe('Registration Page', () => {

  var server, driver;
  const port = 8888,
    domain = `http://localhost:${port}`;

  before(() => {
    server = app.listen(port);
    driver = new webDriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('firefox')
      .build();
  });
  after((done) => {
    server.close(done);
    driver.quit();
  });

  it('Should Render the Registration Page', async () => {
    await driver.get(domain);
    await driver.findElement(By.linkText('Register')).click();
    const title = await driver.findElement(By.css('h1')).getText();
      expect(title).to.include('Register');
    const formElements = await driver.findElement(By.css('form#registrationForm'))
      .findElements(By.css('input'));
      expect(formElements).to.have.length(6);
  });


});
```

The next steps for these tests would be to start testing valid and invalid submissions. Any suggestions, help, or ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To bypass google recaptcha for test you can use specific secret key provided by them on FAQ page and put it on your `test` environment:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-what-should-i-do

> For reCAPTCHA v3, create a separate key for testing environments. Scores may not 
>   be accurate as reCAPTCHA v3 relies on seeing real traffic.
>
> For reCAPTCHA v2, use the following test keys. You will always get No
>   CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.
>
> Site key: **6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI**
>
> Secret key: **6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe**

So you can request this url to verify recaptcha:

> *https*://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=**6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe**&response=anytoken

the response would be like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "challenge_ts": "2019-08-14T07:59:49Z",
  "hostname": "testkey.google.com"
}
```

Please take note that secret key here may be changed, visit the [page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-what-should-i-do) for new test key.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I'm not working on this code base anymore. Hope this helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you use Mocha.

As Google Recaptcha is made to, you cannot test it without human intervention. So to test your app, you need to bypass or mock the recaptcha.
To let you do this, you should mock "userController.validateGoogleCaptcha" to replace it by an async function with (why not) a delay and promise.
Use Rewire (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire). It's same as required but can access and modify called instances.

So I would do something like this.

In your controller test file :

```
const rewire = require("rewire");    
const userController = rewire("userController");
userController.__set__("validateGoogleCaptcha", (req, res, next) => { 
    req.body.captchaSuccess = response.data.success;
    next();
});

//Then your describe tests ...
```

Now userController is mocked to always accept all recaptcha.
You now have to replace it in your calling chain using rewire. The router test maybe a little difficult to mock, you have to re-set your app file with its tested route and then the new userController.